# Trying to use the values in a class array after assigning them but they seemingly disappear

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am creating a Pokemon battler program in c++. I have a pointer array of a Pokemon class, which I have a function to set the values for. The Pokemon class has 3 classes which inherit from it, and each index of the pokemon array is set to one of the pokemon classes. When I set the values for the array and print the info for the array in the same function that I am setting the values, it prints them out fine. However when I try to use the array to print out its info in another function the array seems to be empty and has garbage values. I should also mention the Pokemon class is an abstract class. I don't know enough about c++ to know what I'm doing wrong, and any help would be appreciated.

This picture shows the class with the pokemon array

```
#ifndef TRAINER_H
#define TRAINER_H

#include "pokemon.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Trainer {
    private:
        string name;
        Pokemon* team[3];
    public:
        void test();
        void fight();
        void heal_choice();
        void swap();
        void set_name();
        void pick_team();
        void comp_team();
        Trainer();
};

#endif
```

[trainer.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krG3p.png)
Here is where I'm setting the values of the array. When I use the print_info function in this function the values are correctly outputted. However if I put this same team[0]->print_info() into another function of the trainer class, the values it prints out are random garbage.

```
void Trainer::pick_team(){
    int p1, p2, p3;
    Charmander c1;
    Squirtle s1;
    Bulbasaur b1;
    cout <<"Please choose which 3 pokemon you want in your team. Enter "<<endl;
    cout <<"1 for Charmander, 2 for Squirtle, or 3 for Bulbasaur."<<endl;
    cout <<"The first pokemon you pick will be your starter pokemon."<<endl;
    cout <<"1st pokemon: ";
    cin >> p1;
    cout <<"2nd pokemon: ";
    cin >> p2;
    cout <<"3rd pokemon: ";
    cin >> p3;
    if(p1==1){
        team[0]=&c1;
    }else if(p1==2){
        team[0]=&s1;
    }else{
        team[0]=&b1;
    }
    if(p2==1){
        team[1]=&c1;
    }else if(p2==2){
        team[1]=&s1;
    }else{
        team[1]=&b1;
    }
    if(p3==1){
        team[2]=&c1;
    }else if(p3==2){
        team[2]=&s1;
    }else{
        team[2]=&b1;
    }
    team[0]->print_info();
}
```

[setting values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Batah.png)

All I really need to know it how to be able to correctly set the values of the team array and be able to use the array in other functions.

Comment: It is simpler and faster to put the code into the question as text. It's also one of the rules of this site.

Comment: The things you assign addresses to team[i] are local and are no longer there when the function returns. So the addresses no longer refer to them.

Comment: @doug You are very correct, I'm glad it was such a simple solution. Thank you for the help.